# Page Control like in Reminders app iOS 7

Tags: ios, ios7, reminders

Has anybody found something similar to ios7 Reminder `PageView` with same forces and behavior.

Mean this control.
[image: ios7 Reminder App]

Found something [link](https://github.com/PlenipotentSS/SSStackedPageView) - but it's not exact the same.
Look forward to somebody's help!

Comment: Looks like you can just layer UIViews and animate them appropriately upon tap...

Comment: not exactly, i want to copy it's scroll behaviour with attachment forces, i'm sure it is made with UIDynamics.

Comment: Oh, I see. Yeah, just scrolling in the app now.

Comment: Looks like a combo between UIAttachmentBehavior and bouncing UIScrollviews to me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best solution i have found - [TGLStackedViewController](https://github.com/gleue/TGLStackedViewController/issues)

It provides same behaviour and uses the uidynamics library to attache views in a UICollectionView.